# Can we set tolerance level on regex annotator in Ruta?

Tags: uima, ruta, fault-tolerance

I am annotating `Borrower Name`
`"Borrower Name" -> BorrowerNameKeyword ( "label" = "Borrower Name");`
But I get this text post OCR analysis. At times I might get Borrower Name as `B0rr0wer Nane`. Is this possible to set tolerance limit so that this text gets annotated as BorrowerNameKeyword?

Is their any other approach which could help here?
I could think of dictionary correction but that wont help as it could auto correct right words.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve that with regular expressions in UIMA Ruta. For you particular example  the following rule should work:

```
"B.rr.wer\\sNa.e" -> BorrowerName;
```

Likewise, you can create more variants of regular expressions to cover the OCR errors.

Comment: Please consider marking it as solution if it answers your question.